# wp8-how to access the downloaded file into isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

Hello in my app I download ".mp3" file into isolated storage and user should be able to listen this ".mp3" file but it seems i cant reach ".mp3" file in play click event

here is my code

```
 private IsolatedStorageFile isoStore;
        public mp3kuran()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            using ( isoStore= IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (!isoStore.DirectoryExists("/shared/transfers"))
                {
                    isoStore.CreateDirectory("/shared/transfers");
                }
            }
        }

        string link= "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75638865/001.mp3";

        private BackgroundTransferRequest transferRequest;
```

here is my download button action it downloads the mp3 file

```
        private void download_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Uri transferuri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(link), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
             // Create the new transfer request, passing in the URI of the file to 
            // be transferred.
            transferRequest = new BackgroundTransferRequest(transferuri);
            // Set the transfer method. GET and POST are supported.
            transferRequest.Method = "GET";
            string downloadFile = link.Substring(link.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            Uri downloadUri = new Uri("shared/transfers/" + downloadFile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            transferRequest.DownloadLocation = downloadUri;
            transferRequest.Tag = downloadFile;
            // Add the transfer request using the BackgroundTransferService. Do this in 
            // a try block in case an exception is thrown.
            try
            {
                BackgroundTransferService.Add(transferRequest);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to add background transfer request. " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to add background transfer request.");
            }

        }
```

here play button click event

```
        private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = transferRequest.Tag;
            MessageBox.Show(fileName);

            using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (isoStore.FileExists(fileName))
                {MessageBox.Show("here");
                    using (var isoStream = isoStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        mediaSound.Stop();
                        mediaSound.SetSource(isoStream);

                        mediaSound.Position = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
                        mediaSound.Volume = 20;
                        mediaSound.Play();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

in play_clic event i try to reach mp3 from isolated storage but i couldnt solve what is wrong because when I click button ,it does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas...

Are you checking the BackgroundTransferRequest has completed before allowing the play button to be clicked?

Are you sure the complete file has been successfully downloaded by checking for the presence of a physical file, the same size as the original? You can use a tool like [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) to check this.

It does the Tag property on your BackgroundTransferRequest maintain the correct value after the download is complete?

Normally you'd check the status of the BackgroundTransferRequest and copy the file out of "/shared/transfers" to your own location. You'd then play the file from that location.